# Say currency with Spanish

Tags: text-to-speech, ssml

I want to play text to speech with ssml.

```
var prompt = new StringBuilder();.
prompt.Append(@"<say-as type = ""currency"">$");
prompt.Append({0}); 
prompt.Append(@"</say-as>");
```

Then we can Play prompt.ToString() as TTS.

It works fine for English. The currency is spoken as "X dollars Y cents". However if I use Spanish, should I change something? As it is still speaking English.

I use Microsoft Speech Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voice engine server is not set correctly. A new dll is replaced then it is resolved.